# Sum Column D Until Condition is Met, Return Column A Value in Target Column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

The object is to display the date in Column E on which target heat units will be reached for an event.  Heat units begin accumulating the day *after* the event.

Column A - Date
Column B - Daily Temperature High
Column C - Daily Temperature Low
Column D - Daily Heat Units
Column E - Target 40 Heat Units

My level of expertise ends at VLOOKUP.  Thank you for any guidance.

GalAbra I have looked at a number of functions including MATCH, INDEX and at many Stackoverflow posts but don't have code or formula experience enough to recognize what will work.  I have no code or formula to share.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJLNY.png)

In the example image, to find when 40 heat units (E4) is achieved for an event on 05/02 (A4) begin SUM at D5.  D5:D7 achieves the target of 40 on 05/05 (A7).  Place A7 value in E4.  Repeat to solve F4 and G4.

Fletch, you are very close.  Beginning at D5 I'd like to add the numbers in column D until they add up to the number in E1 (40).  Whatever row that is, I'd then like to place the date value of column A in E4.  I will experiment with your suggestion.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please attach an example, ans/or make your explanation more clear

Comment: When asking questions, we need to provide a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are trying to do.

Based on my understanding. You want to SUM the values in D between the 2 dates under 40 HU, 49 HU & 56 HU.

Using `=SUM(INDIRECT("D"&MATCH(E2,$A:$A,0)&":D"&MATCH(E3,$A:$A,0)))` under a new column (H) for [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pBav.png)

Then drag the formula across to the following 2 columns.

The INDIRECT enables you to mix strings and values within cells to make up your SUM. MATCH is used to return an integer (number) of the 'matching' cell to the date in cell 'E2' for the start date and 'E3' for the end date. Whilst use of the '&' is to concatenate the string ("D") and the integer (number) to return 'D5' start and 'D6' end.

Hope this helps.